# How to use Spring-DM with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, osgi, spring-dm

Could anyone guide how to use spring-DM with spring boot to develop micro-services?
How it is helpful while developing micro-services?

Comment: Spring DM is a dead project, and has long since been transfered into the Eclipse Virgo project.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. Could you suggest any other osgi framework that we can use with spring boot micro-service application.

Comment: Why would you need OSGi with microservices. Also using Spring DM (or Virgo) beats the purpose of Spring Boot imho.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. I am studying OSGI and try to relate it in Spring boot application. I am trying to make a spring boot micro-service that follow Todays industry best standard. Could you please give some inputs?

Comment: _I am studying OSGI and try to relate it in Spring boot application_ - that's completely wrong approach. You should either study OSGi (and use Felix, Karaf, ...) *or* Spring Boot (and Spring Framework). It's like saying _I am studying SOAP Web Services and try to relate it in REST_.